# Pass arguments to multiple forms with the same request in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new in django and I have a doubt:
Is possible pass arguments to a several forms.

Scenario:
I have an html table rendered with django-tables2, in the first column I have a drop down button. One item from the drop down button open a bootstrap modal window with 3 diffetent forms(all the forma re modelbased forms).
The arguments are pased with a javascript function, the function take the value from some cells of the html table and send this value as argument. 
All this form take the same arguments. I can pass the arguments to one form but I need to pass the arguments to all the forms.

In simple words:
How can I pass arguments to various forms in the same post request?

How I say above I am new with django and I don't know if is possible get this functionality.
**UPDATE**
my forms: (all the forms have the same code. nonly the name change)

```
class RecepcionForm(forms.ModelForm):
       def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(RecepcionForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper(self)
       self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save','Grabar'))
    class Meta:
       model = DetalleRecepcion
```

my views:(all the form use a view like this. only the name of the view change

```
def RecepcionView(request):
    idp = request.GET.get('i')
    anio = request.GET.get('a')
    mes = request.GET.get('m')
    if request.method == 'POST':
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       form = RecepcionForm(request.POST, instance=r)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
    else:
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       form = RecepcionForm(instance=r)

    return render_to_response('recepcion.html',
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I only know how to pass the value to an unique form. I use this fucntion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function param(){
  var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var rows = tbl.rows;
  var argu = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
   rows[i].onclick =  function(){
   idpro = this.cells;
  argu = "?i="+idpro[0].innerHTML+"&a="+idpro[1].innerHTML+"&m="+idpro[2].innerHTML;
   window.location = "/recepcion/"+argu;
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

I know that function is really bad coding, but I have some trouble to redirect toe the template using ajax post request.
I try to use this function but I can never redirect to the form where i send the parameters

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function param(){
 $(function(){
  //var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var rows = tbl.rows;
  var url = "/recepcion/";
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
   rows[i].onclick =  function(){
   idpro = this.cells;
   ano = this.cells;
   mes1 = this.cells;
   $.ajax({
    async : false,
    type:"GET",
    url: "/recepcion/",
    datatype: 'json',
    data: ({i: idpro[0].innerHTML, a: ano[1].innerHTML, m: mes1[2].innerHTML }),
    success: function(){
      }
    });
   }
  }
 });
 return false;
}
</script>
```

Any idea or advice how can I achieve this functionality.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: pass argument to form? how are you doing this?

Comment: I try to use an ajax function, but I have some problem and now I am using a really bad coding javascript function